# OpenSSH downgrade attack

Tags: linux, ssh

I have tried to implement a downgrade attack against the SSH protocol as the first steps (encryption protocols exchange) are not signed, as per [RFC4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-7.1).
The idea is to intercept (mitm) these steps and replace strong algorithms by weaker algorithms supported by both sides.

The replacement is working well, and server and client receive a weakened list of supported algorithms.
However, the communication is directly interrupted when the server receive the client's list.

I have expected some protection against downgrade attack to be implemented by the protocol, but I don't see nowhere in RFC (or log files) how.
SSL proceeds for instance by resending the first steps encrypted, to let the other side discover what the first steps were, and avoid this way any downgrade attack. But there is no re-send of anything tcpdump says.

What mechanisms prevent downgrade attacks on SSH?

Many thanks, and don't hesitate to ask for implementation details.

Comment: Well the server can be configured to accept only particular ssh versions right?

Comment: Thanks for answering; This is not about version (I keep version 2 anyway) it's about algorithms exchanged during the first step. I take the default Ubuntu configuration files and try, choosing the weaker algorithm supported by both client and server, force them to use altering the exchanged packets. I'm wondering which mechanism prevents to complete this task.

Comment: Right so you're saying the diffie hellman key exchanges and the mac encodings can be compromised?

Comment: At the very steps, there is no intervention of DH. Server displays its banner, and client send its supported encryption algorithms. And as a reply, server sends its own supported encryption algorithms. These steps are not subject yet to DH, and anyway, DH is not MITM proof. When client and server have sent their supported algorithms, client sends a packet, and receiving it, servers closes communication. I just would like to know what in this packet reveals the attack. Log file shows error: buffer_get_bignum2_ret: BN_bin2bn failed [preauth]
fatal: buffer_get_ecpoint: buffer error [preauth]

Comment: Not that i can help, but i found the question interesting. So which part of it during this stage? The key exchange initialisation? http://www.mnin.org/write/2006_sshcrypto.html

Answer (score 5):

There is downgrade protection in the SSH protocol. The server and the client perform the DH/ECDH key exchange and calculate the shared secret. This shared secret, along with the server and client version strings and algorithm lists are hashed to produce a symmetric key.

If you change the supported algorithms, the server and the client will calculate different symmetric keys, unless you have a preimage attack on the hash function which also works if some of the input is secret.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, this is from [section 8 of RFC4253](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253#section-8), specifically the part about computing the "exchange hash".